# Create a playlist of URLs in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have a list to links of flv files (not youtube or anything like that.) The problem is that you can't embed them, you need to use a flv player. Instead, I would like to open them all in VLC as a playlist, but as far as I can see, you can only open them using 'network stream' one by one. Ideally, I'd like to take the list and copy/paste them somehow into VLC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this

### Using the GUI

1. Hit *CTRL+L* to open up the playlist window in VLC.
2. Right click in the playlist window and choose *Advanced Open...*
3. Click on the *Network* tab, enter the URL, and hit *Enqueue*
4. Repeat this for each of the URLs

### Using the command line

Use this syntax:

```
vlc <URL 1> <URL 2> <URL 3> ...
```

### Using an external tool

You can create an XSPF playlist using an external tool [like this one](http://tvtvtv.ru/tools/plc_eng.php). Then, just open the playlist with VLC.

Answer (score 10):

Put links into a plain text file separated by newlines and save as `*.m3u`. Then open it with vlc.

Comment: This is so awesome! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use this open source project to generate your playlist : https://github.com/sybaris/PlayListGenerator

Regards,

Sybaris

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User! Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)