# Launching VLC using an html link

Tags: vlc-media-player, html

I am trying to stream my media library over my lan by listing them all on a html file. Chrome has native supports h.264 so files encoded in h.264 is not an issue by about 30% of my media is encoded using h.265 which is not supported by chorme yet. Vlc has a browser plugin but that uses NPAPI which has been depreciated in chrome. So is it possible to launch vlc by clicking a html link for streaming videos similar to magnet links for torrents? Or is there any other way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Could I make a program in c/c++  that would launch vlc with the appropriate video source (example: http://192.168.1.10/video.mkv) and register it to a [URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)? I don't know how this URI scheme works, but would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can open http links to files directly, so you can right-click a link, "Advanced Open..." -> "Network tab".

This is similar to [Create a playlist of URLs in VLC](https://superuser.com/questions/654125/create-a-playlist-of-urls-in-vlc) - But *note a on step 4: you don't hit "Enqueue" anymore, but "open"*